# Mass Effect 3: Using Wench Coalesced Editor - Can only change part of Concussive Shot power?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mods

I have been messing around with the Wench Coalesced Editor to edit some power properties for the Soldier class.

Now it seems that the Concussive Shot has - in part at least - some locked values that can't be changed by editing. It's located under

```
biogame.ini >sfxgamecontent > sfxpowercustomaction > concussiveshot
```

I can change values of the evolutions (ranks 4-6), but the first three ranks seem locked. Which is strange, because I could change any other power at any given rank. Furthermore, the base damage is also way off, based on the Mass Effect Wikia (rank 1 = 200 damage instead of 100). This means, the value must come from somewhere else. I don't know, whether or not it only applies to Concussive Shot or if there are other powers with similar restrictions.

Why is Concussive Shot only partially moddable?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I already found the answer. The Concussive Shot's damage was changed in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\Mass Effect 3\BIOGame\DLC\DLC_UPD_Patch02\CookedPCConsole\default.sfar
```

where I extracted the analogue to the original Coalesced.bin (DLC_UPD_Patch02.bin). Guess I will have to look through the DLC files in the future if a power (or any other entry) proves to be resistant against modifying.